# NoReverseMatch in Django not working tried everything

Tags: python, django

Reverse for 'projectDetail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects/(?P<projectinfo_id>[0-9]+)/$']

**Request Method:** GET

**Request URL:**    http://localhost:8000/projects/yourprojects

**Django Version:** 3.0.4

**Exception Type:** NoReverseMatch

**Exception Value:** Reverse for 'projectDetail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects/(?P<projectinfo_id>[0-9]+)/$']

**urls.py file**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('newproject', views.newproject, name='newproject'),
    path('yourprojects', views.yourprojects, name='yourprojects'),
    path('<int:projectinfo_id>/', views.projectDetail, name='projectDetail'),
]
```

**views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Projectinfo
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt,csrf_protect


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'projects/home.html')

def yourprojects(request):
    projectinfo = Projectinfo.objects
    return render(request, 'projects/yourprojects.html', {'projectinfo':projectinfo})


@login_required
def newproject(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['branch'] and request.POST['directorate'] and request.POST['email'] and request.POST['program_service'] and request.POST['giturl']:
            projectinfo = Projectinfo()
            projectinfo.title = request.POST['title']
            projectinfo.branch = request.POST['branch']
            projectinfo.directorate = request.POST['directorate']
            projectinfo.email = request.POST['email']
            projectinfo.program_service = request.POST['program_service']
            if request.POST['giturl'].startswith('http://') or request.POST['giturl'].startswith('https://'):
                projectinfo.giturl = request.POST['giturl']
            else:
                projectinfo.giturl = 'http://' + request.POST['giturl']
            projectinfo.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            projectinfo.project_lead = request.user
            projectinfo.save()
            return redirect('/projects/' + str(projectinfo.id))
        else:
            return render(request, 'projects/newproject.html', {'error': 'All fields are required'})


    else:
        return render(request, 'projects/newproject.html')


def projectDetail(request, projectinfo_id):
    projectinfo = get_object_or_404(Projectinfo, pk=projectinfo_id)
    return render(request, 'projects/projectDetail.html', {'projectinfo': projectinfo})
```

**yourprojects.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}


{% load static %}

<main>

    <div class="container">

      <h3 class="center">Your Projects</h3>

  {% for projectinfo in projectinfo.all %}
  <div class="row" onclick="window.location='{% url 'projectDetail' projectinfo.id %}';">
    <div class="col s6 m6">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title">{{ projectinfo.title }}</span>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img class="align-center" src="{% static 'Images/RandESmall.svg' %}" width="179" height="135">
          </div>
          <p>This is ROE Comments. A projects that uses natural language processing to help improve and streamline the EI Process.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a class="center" href="{% url 'projectDetail' projectinfo.id %}">View / Edit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</main>

{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assurance Tool</title>

<!-- Google and Font Awesome  -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Materilize CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialize.min.css' %}"  media="screen,projection"/>

<!-- My Css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

</head>
<body>

  <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="{% url 'yourprojects' %}"><i class="material-icons">scatter_plot</i>Your Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'impacttool' %}"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i>Assess Impact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Support</a></li>
  </ul>


    <div class="navbar-fixed valign-wrapper ">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper light-blue darken-2" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
          <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'AIGLogo.svg' %}" width="55" height="55"></a>
          <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="{% url 'newproject' %}">New Project</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}">LOGOUT</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-trigger center-align" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1"><img src="{% static 'profile_icon.svg' %}" width="25" height="25"></a></li>
              <form id="logout" method="POST" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden" />
              </form>
              {% else %}
            <li><a href="#methodology">METHODOLOGY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">LOGIN</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">SIGNUP</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="sidenav">
            <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" data-target="nav-mobile" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>


<main>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
</main>


      <footer class="page-footer light-blue darken-2" style="width:100%">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col l6 s12">
              <h5 class="white-text">We are here to help!</h5>
              <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">The AI Assurace Tool is just one way to work with our team. If you would like a more peronal touch please do not hesitate to contact use.</p>


            </div>
            <div class="col l3 s12">
              <h5 class="white-text">Connect</h5>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Contact Team</a></li>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">FRIDA Website</a></li>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#!"></a></li>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">AI COE</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col l3 s12">
              <h5 class="white-text">Support</h5>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Help</a></li>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Report Issues</a></li>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Other Resources</a></li>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">FAQ</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
          <div class="container">
          Made by <a class="orange-text text-lighten-3" href="#">FRIDA</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>


<!-- Materlize Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/materialize.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/materialize.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/init.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think your error matches the code you've posted. ` 'projectDetail' with no arguments` suggests that you have `{% url 'projectDetail' %}` somewhere, but in your template you have `{% url 'projectDetail' projectinfo.id %}`. Make sure you've saved all your files and restarted the server, and included the exact code and error in your question here.

Comment: This is why i am so confused by this error. I have provided everything... the exact code and error to my question. My projectDetail page is working, The error only occurs on the yourprojects page.

Comment: The problem could be in your `base.html`

Comment: As an aside, I don't like the repeated variable in `{% for projectinfo in projectinfo.all %}`. It would be clearer if you passed `{'projectinfos': Projectinfo.objects.all()}` to the template, then looped through `{% for projectinfo in projectinfos %}`. But that's not what's causing your error.

Comment: Thanks for the aside :)

Comment: @Alasdair I think  you are correct about the problem being in my `base.html`. This error has comes up in addition to what i sent: `In template assurancetool-project/assurancetool/templates/base.html, error at line 0`

Comment: We can't help you debug the `base.html` unless you add it to your answer.

Comment: @Alasdair i have added the base.html

Comment: I'm out of ideas - I still can't see anything in your code that would cause the *with no arguments* error. Perhaps you've forgotten to save your code or commit/push/pull changes or restart your server, and you're not running the code you think you are. If you're sure that's not the case, then I'd start with the simplest possible `projects/yourprojects.html` (don't even extend `base.html` to begin with), and gradually add more complexity so that you can find the code that is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Alasdair. I will see what if i can find the issue and report back!